# ODBC : Array of Parameters - ignoring parameter

Tags: c++, c, sql-server, sql-server-2008, odbc

It is possible to ignore one/some parameter of one/some specific rows during a insert/update using array of parameters.

I provide a simple example. Imagine that we have one table with 3 columns: X, Y and Z. And we want perform an update in block (please ignore if some parameter is missing, it is not relevant for discussion):

```c
#define N_ROWS_PER_BLOCK 100
int h_x[N_ROWS_PER_BLOCK];
int h_y[N_ROWS_PER_BLOCK];
int h_z[N_ROWS_PER_BLOCK];

// Fill h_x, h_y and h_z with the values that we want - doesn't matter to this question
// (...)
strexec = "UPDATE table SET X = ?, Y = ?, Z = ?"

SQLBindParameter(stmt_handle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SLONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, h_x, 0, NULL);
SQLBindParameter(stmt_handle, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SLONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, h_y, 0, NULL);
SQLBindParameter(stmt_handle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SLONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, h_z, 0, NULL);

SQLSetStmtAttr(stmt_handle, SQL_ATTR_PARAMSET_SIZE, (SQLPOINTER)N_ROWS_PER_BLOCK, 0);
SQLExecDirectA ( stmt_handle, (SQLCHAR*)strexec , SQL_NTS );
```

**Question**: Now imagine that, for some reason, we want that in row #60 parameter X should be ***ignored*** in statement execution. The advantage of this is that we can prepare a statement with "all columns/attributes" and update only the attributes/columns that we want in each row.

How i can do this, if possible? Can me pointing to some (dummy) example?

I read ODBC documentation i and know that is possible to ignore a (complete) row (a set of parameters) using **SQL_ATTR_PARAM_OPERATION_PTR** attribute and setting SQL_PARAM_PROCEED or SQL_PARAM_IGNORED, but i **don't want to ignore all attributes of the row**, **just one parameter of the row**.

**EDIT:**

I found this at IBM ODBC documentation (extended indicators):

- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.odbc%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_afarinp.htm
- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.odbc%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_fnbindparameter.htm

"ODBC applications can use extended indicators to update all columns in UPDATE, INSERT, and MERGE statements without specifying the current value of columns that do not require changes.

If you use extended indicators you do not need to code separate INSERT statements for every combination of columns that you want to insert"

SQL_UNASSIGNED: "The target column of the bound parameter is ignored for UPDATE, and MERGE UPDATE operations. The parameter is handled the same way as the DEFAULT keyword for INSERT, and MERGE INSERT operations."

Is this possible with Native Client? In Microsoft Documentation doesn't appear any references for SQL_UNASSIGNED.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and prepare 2 statements:

```
strexec1 = "UPDATE table SET X = ?, Y = ?, Z = ?";
strexec2 = "UPDATE table SET Y = ?, Z = ?"
```

Then just choose what statement should be executed in batch

Comment: Indeed, but in this case we have, at least, 4 client-server network roundtrips.

1 roundtrip for the first prepare,
1 roundtrip to execute,
1 roundtrip for the second prepare,
1 roundtrip to execute.

I want to avoid the last 2 roundtrips :)

Comment: @dim As I understand from "..in row #60 parameter.." you anyway start statement multiple times, let me just mention that both statements will be done in the same connection. If you doubt about network round-trip then you should use stored procedure - where you made distinguish if X should be used as param

Comment: Ok, this is a possibility but it is better to avoid 2 separate updates. I don't want one update to update only columns Y and Z on row #60...i prefer another way to update X, Y and Z (using only one execution) and ignore parameter X in row #60.

Example:
h_x[59] = 11; h_y[59] = 11; h_z[59] = 11;
h_x[60] = DONT CARE! ; h_y[60] = 12; h_z[60] = 12;
h_x[61] = 12; h_y[61] = 12; h_z[61] = 12;

//Bind X parameter, Y parameter and Z parameter
//Execute

And after execute, <row 60, column x> was not updated because i want to ignore it.

Comment: @dim then you can use MSSQL trigger - if instead X NULL (as argument) was specified - just provide logic that use previous value from existing row

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I found this: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.odbc%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_extdindicators.htm
"ODBC applications can use extended indicators to update all columns in UPDATE, INSERT, and MERGE statements without specifying the current value of columns that do not require changes"

SQL_UNASSIGNED: "The target column of the bound parameter is ignored for UPDATE, and MERGE UPDATE operations. "
With native client is this possible?

Comment: ".. is this possible?" - you need try